# Installing nginx's updated version (1.11.x) on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and following [this well-known guide](https://thangamaniarun.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/how-to-install-latest-version-of-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04/).

Currently I'm getting errors after doing the following:

1) creating `nginx.list` in`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`,

2) doing `sudo wget –q –O– http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | sudo apt–key add -`

3) `sudo apt-get update`

The errors are:

```
N: Ignoring file 'nginx_signing.key' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'deb–src' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What's the problem and how do I fix it?

---

`nginx.list` contains the following:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
deb–src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ trusty nginx
```

Comment: What's the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list` file?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: added that in the question. Sorry to have missed that info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you copied the commands verbatim from the website. The website "prettifies" some characters, among them the hyphen. It replaces the ASCII character `-` with `–`, which are not easily distinguishable.

Replace all occurrences of `–` in the commands with the correct hyphen and run the commands again.

Example:

```
deb–src http://... # wrong character
deb-src http://... # correct character
   ^- this character is different
```

Comment: Jesus Christ! That thing was dancing around in my subconscious "hmm, it looks odd, but whatever...". Great spot my man! Thanks!

Comment: So it all worked out, except, in the end I got `Ignoring file 'nginx_signing.key' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension`. However, `nginx -v` tells me I have `1.13.5` now. What's the ignore warning for?

Comment: The file `nginx_signing.key` does not belong in that directory. Just remove it. It shouldn't have been saved there anyway, it happend because of the wrong hyphen character again.

Comment: Oh, I didn't change dir from `/sources.list.d/` when I was running `wget`. What's the correct dir for it?

Comment: You don't need it. If you run the wget command with the correct characters it downloads the file and pipes it to the `apt-key` command directly without storing it on the disk. Just remove the file.

Comment: Peculiarly, if I do `sudo apt-get install nginx`, I get `1.13.x`. However, if I try `sudo apt-get install nginx-naxsi` (installing the third-party `naxsi` WAF alongwith nginx), my nginx version remains at `1.4.x`. This is for a separate question really, but I thought I'd quickly run it by you in case you have a clue?